# Google is fetching a UK page when I insert a Dutch URL. I want to know how to fix this

Tags: search, console, seo, fetch

When I try to Fetch a page like: https://www.suitsuit.com/nl/koffers/caretta-cool-gray/tr-12268 Google returns this page: /en/suitcases/caretta-cool-gray/tr-12264 It is the English version. We are working on the HREF tags but this is not yet implemented. We first want to fix this issue. Google is showing English meta tags with Dutch URL's in the Search Engine Result page too. See screenshot link

[image: this is a screenshot of Searchconsole which show I try to fetch a /nl url and Google is rendering a /en page]

This is the case with all my product pages, and only my product pages. The blog pages, category pages and homepage is fetched correctly.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the user agent, the server responded with the English version because of the language settings of Google Bot.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, as you mentioned, you can put lang tags and it might work for Bing/Yahoo, like:

```
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head lang="en">
```

But, if we talk about Google: it uses only the visible content of your page to determine its language and don’t use any code-level language information such as lang attributes. Try to check more on [Google Support Page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?authuser=0#1)

Instead of this, you can show alternative versions of page using hreflang tags:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl" href="http://example.com/nl/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://example.com/en/" />
```

Also, you can try to specify exact version for exact country:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="be-nl" href="http://be.example.com/nl/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href="http://en.example.com/gb/" />
```

But, don't forget to add default version for users with language that you have no special page for:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

Also, additionally about Google, if you want to do targeting by country -  add different language/country versions URLs into [Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/) as separate sites and configure this through "Search Traffic -> International Targeting"